# Unity lobby manager matchmaker not visible on linux server

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, amazon-ec2, unity-networking

I'm using unity's [Network lobby](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/network-lobby-41836) and it seems to be working fine on windows. I'm having one client act as a dedicated server. When I create a lobby I can view the lobby in the matchmaker on another instance of my game just fine.

[image]

The only issue is when I build the 
game on my AWS linux ec2 instance and run the server I cannot see the available match on my windows machine.

I suspected this was something to do with port forwarding but I realized I could do netstat --listen and find which port the matchmaker was listening on and manually ping it using telnet to "connect" to the game. So the game is being hosted but just isn't visible.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? The documentation on the [matchmaker](https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/Manual/UNetMatchMaker.html) doesn't really tell me much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't working was because my AWS server is on NA and my computer is in EU so the matches weren't visible. I changed the the Matchmaker host URI to us1-mm.unet.unity3d.com and now it works fine.